# Correct use of embedded interfaces within Go struct

Tags: go

I am attempting to port some Python code over to Go. The Python code has a State class which has 2 abstract classes Packable and Hashable which unmarshal/marshal and then hash/digest the data from the class into bytes.

I was thinking of porting it over to Go by doing the following, having 2 interfaces, Hasher and Packer, and then embedding these in my State struct like below.

```
type State struct {
    FQDN   string

    common.Hasher
    common.Packer
}

// Hasher generates a hash of the data.
type Hasher interface {
    Hash(h hash.Hash) (string, error)
    Digest() ([]byte, error)
}

// Packer is an interface for serialising and deserialising requests.
type Packer interface {
    // Marshal returns the JSON encoding of v.
    Marshal() ([]byte, error)
    // Unmarshal parses the JSON-encoded data and stores the result in the value pointed.
    Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error
}
```

Would best practice now be for me to create a constructor and pass in implementations of Hasher and Packer? Or should I implement the interface methods on the struct like below

```
// Marshal takes the node state and converts it into an array of bytes.
func (s *State) Marshal() ([]byte, error) {
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(s)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return bytes, nil
}
```

I am trying to work out what the most Go way of doing this is. I started along the lines of attaching the interface methods to my struct but when I create a new state it still allows me to call methods of the interfaces I haven't implemented and I get nil pointers.

Thanks!

Comment: Implement the interface methods on the struct. You don't need to declare the interfaces until you actually use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would only work as written if the implementations of `Hasher` and `Packer` don't need to know anything about the type they're embedded in (which they won't), in which case they should probably just be plain functions.

It seems like what you really want here is to define methods on `State` so that the `State` type implements `Hasher` and `Packer`, in which case you should *not* embed those interfaces. Just define the methods on `State` correctly.

Interfaces are demonstrated in the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/10).